# Как лучше организовать мультиязычность на сайте?

Tags: i18n

Как лучше организовать мультиязычность на сайте, через  поддомены(en.mydomain.com/index или ru.mydomain.com/index) или может лучше просто добавкой части пути(mydomain.com/ru/index или mydomain.com/en/index)? Добавлю, что сайт не сильно большой и на счёт "лучше", имеется в виду индексация поисковиками и дальнейшей работы сеошником.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы выбрал поддомены. Смотрится аккуратнее, плюс есть четкое разделение по языковым особенностям.

Можно, конечно, сделать разделение и на базе одного домена, но данная идея мне нравится не сильно, просто в силу того, что в общем списке страниц сайта будут страницы на разных языках.

Если вы неприменимо, хотите чтобы все страницы вашего сайта были на домене 2-го уровня, то можете зарегистрировать несколько доменов. Например comru.ru comen.com и так далее. Идея извращенческая, но такие сайты тоже встречаются (например яндекс, гугл).

ЗЫ. Большинство крупных сайтов для работы с языками используют поддомены.
Но некоторые поступают и другими способами.

Comment: если сайт небольшой, боюсь, что поддомену уведут трафик, которого и так не очень то и много будет.

Comment: @ashalbulk , а что Вам мешает вести общую статистику по основному сайту и поддоменам? Яндекс.Метрика и гугл аналитикс это дают возможность делать.

Answer (score 2):

Выбор между субдоменом или "папкой" не сыграет большого приоритета, так как для робота нужно указывать явное определение.

Для этого следует использовать канонические ссылки (основные) они задаются с помощью rel="canonical" в head страницы, отдельно для русскоязычной и отдельно для англоязычной,

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/ru/downloads"/> <!-- русскоязычная версия -->
<link rel="canonical" href="/en/downloads"/> <!-- англоязычная версия -->
```

таким образом роботы будут определять обе ссылки как оригинальный контент.
Для пользователей лучше всего реализовать выбор языка на странице, ведь прописывать что-то вначале домена или в конце они будут неохотно.

Более детально изучить данный аспект можно по ссылке
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru

Comment: Идея хороша и однозначно правильная, но зачем реализовывать выбор языка? Ведь некоторые пользователи могут отвалиться увидев страницу входа не на родном языке?

Делаем сразу переадресацию на версию сайта на подходящем языке. Таким образом пользователю не придется выбирать язык самому. Конечно, функцию переключения нужно предусмотреть, но лучше чтобы это делалось автоматически.